# Create trust between domains via Internet, because of company acquisition

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, port-forwarding

We want user from the newly acquired company (domain b.com) to be able to authenticate to our helpdesk system in domain a.com via Active Directory. We do not have a point-to-point VPN to the new location and we are not planning to have one. Both company use static IPs for Internet access.

In both domains, the DNS server is a Domain Controller.  Any pointer on what port(s) I need to open/forward so that I can create a trust between the two domain so that new users can authenticate to our helpdesk system?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is relatively complex and is outlined in [this excellent TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773178(v=ws.10).aspx).

Honestly, doing this without a site-to-site VPN is a **BAD** idea for a lot of reasons. I'd strongly reconsider that stance. If you can't afford proper hardware VPN endpoints, you could always use something like OpenVPN at each end. It even comes in a virtual appliance for super-easy delivery.

Comment: agreed...use a VPN between the two domains/locations.  You'll need it regardless..there's no point in opening up ports to establish a trust if the clients can't access all the resources they need.

Comment: Thanks for all the reply, we mostly wanted them to be able to access our helpdesk system that is web-base so we would have just opened a port and pointed them to that in their web browser but since most of you seem to agree this is a bad way of doing it I will look at having a site to site vpn. I will see if I can find these virtual appliance for super-easy delivery mentioned by MDMarra above.

Comment: It's much more than just `"opening a port"`.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772723%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) is MS's list of ports required by feature.

As ErikA correctly points out this should really be over a VPN, I'd just assumed one was already in place sorry.

Comment: Linking to that without mentioning the necessity of VPN is nearly downvote-worthy. :)

Comment: You *can* do it all over SSL though...   but you're right, I'll add.

Comment: True. It just seems dirty to do it without VPN, SSL or not.